# Importing python-pptx: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'

Tags: python, module, python-pptx

I'm running Python 3.6.6rc1 on macOS Mojave (10.14.1) and I'm trying to import python-pptx

Currently, my first line is causing a problem:

```
import python-pptx
```

---

I deleted that and added this, to no avail.

```
from pptx import Presentation
```

---

This is my error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'
```

---

I have downloaded python-pptx using pip:

```
sudo pip install python-pptx
```

---

Running `pip show python-pptx` in the Terminal, I get:

```
Name: python-pptx
Version: 0.6.16
Summary: Generate and manipulate Open XML PowerPoint (.pptx) files
Home-page: http://github.com/scanny/python-pptx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-pptx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: lxml, Pillow, XlsxWriter
Required-by:
```

As you can see, the `Location` is different than the `Version`. Is that a problem?

---

Running `sys.path` in the shell shows:

```
['/Users/gstrickland/Desktop', '/Users/gstrickland/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

---

Running `python -m pip show python-pptx` I get this:

```
Name: python-pptx
Version: 0.6.16
Summary: Generate and manipulate Open XML PowerPoint (.pptx) files
Home-page: http://github.com/scanny/python-pptx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-pptx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: /Users/gstrickland/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: lxml, Pillow, XlsxWriter
Required-by:
```

Different location, but still in `2.7`

---

Running `python -c'import sys; print(sys.path)'` gives me:

```
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/gstrickland/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

---

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you actually install pptx? Did you do so on the same Python installation you're trying to import it on?

Comment: @user2357112 Of course. Sorry I forgot to add that. Edited.

Comment: It is likely that the `pip` you get with `sudo` corresponds to a different Python than what you're using.

Comment: Can we see `$ pip show python-pptx` from shell, and `print(sys.path)` from the python file?

Comment: @JacobIRR All that does is show the information about the module, such as the version and creator.

Comment: @SanguineL It should show `Location:` that's what matters in this case, since that directory should also appear inside your `sys.path`: `$ pip show python-pptx | grep Location`

Comment: (If you find a mismatch, please do not try to fix it by messing with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`. Doing so is likely to break things harder.)

Comment: @JacobIRR Fixed

Comment: Yup, you've installed it on the wrong Python. Run `python -m pip install --user ...` instead of `sudo pip install ...` to install things, or use a virtualenv.

Comment: You are using pip in a python 2.7 context and your sys path shows version 3. Upgrade to pip3 and try that.

Comment: @user2357112 Post a full answer and I'll accept it for you.

Comment: This is what worked from me in Mac terminal. Run python3 -m pip install python-pptx , instead of sudo pip install ...

Answer (score 8):

You need to install python-pptx package as :

```
pip install python-pptx
```

You can test the code to verify installation :

```
from pptx import Presentation


def main():
    prs = Presentation()
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    title = slide.shapes.title
    subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

    title.tetx = "Hello World fromm pptx"
    subtitle.text = "using python-ppts!!!"
    prs.save("test.pptx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've installed python-pptx with a pip corresponding to the system Python 2.7, not the Python 3.6 you're trying to use. Install things with

```
python -m pip install --user ...
```

instead of

```
sudo pip install ...
```

to ensure you're using the right pip for your Python, and to avoid some of the other problems associated with running pip through sudo.

Comment: Wait. It didn't work. Still getting the same result. I have uninstalled pip, python-pptx, and python multiple times, but it didn't change at all. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: @SanguineL: Show us the output of `python -m pip show python-pptx` and `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`.

Comment: Edits added to post.

Comment: @SanguineL: Your `python` isn't Python 3.6 either. Figure out how to run your Python 3.6 from the shell, then use that Python to run `python -m pip ...`.

Comment: @SanguineL: Don't uninstall the system Python. You'll break things a lot worse than they are now. As for using Python 3.6, perhaps run `print(sys.executable)` in whatever unspecified shell you're using that's using Python 3.6, then use that Python to run pip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184642/discussion-between-sanguinel-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the module is available in any of the paths printed by "sys.path".
Either the module isn't installed or isn't available in module search path.